I have ran the same android project with target sdk 34 and again with target sdk 28 after uninstalled older APK.File is not created with targetsdk28
I have an android project with target SDK 28 in which folder and a file will be created in External storage that is worked fine when I tested with Android 14 device.
I taken a git branch on top of this project and updated the target SDK version to 34 and and implemented all files access permission and tested the branch folder and file is created as well in Android 14 devices.
when I uninstalled and switch to my old project with target SDK 28, the File and folder are not created in external storage like earlier.
My doubt is I have uninstalled the apk with target SDK version 34 and installed apk with target SDK 28 then why the file is not creating in external storage. I am confused.
2024-08-13 11:02:53.255 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:574)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.255 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.255 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at com.qbriktest.LogManager.logStr(LogManager.java:214)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.255 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at com.qbriktest.LogManager.printVersionInLog(LogManager.java:327)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.255 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at com.qbriktest.BuildBrand.init(BuildBrand.java:129)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.255 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at com.qbriktest.shaktiapp.ApplicationClass.onCreate(ApplicationClass.java:222)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.255 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1317)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7523)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2394)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:206)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:295)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8733)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:577)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.256 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1053)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.258 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W  Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.258 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.258 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.258 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:274)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.258 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.258 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8616)
2024-08-13 11:02:53.258 15056-15056 System.err              com.qbrik.shaktiapp                  W      at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:560)```


After a factory reset, file and folder generating in that Android 14 device with target SDK 28 project, kindly share the reason behind this strange behaviour if anyone knows.
